# Where exactly to see particular index data in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am very new to ELK stack.Now i am able create custom index in elastic search by using log-stash and i can see created index in *9200/_plugin/head/ url . But want to view those created indexes/inside data in kibana.
I have kibana homepage *9200/_plugin/kibana/#/dashboard/file/default.json
Can any one suggest please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is for Kibana 8:

**Open "Manage Spaces"**
[image]

**Open "Data Views" --> "Create data view**
[image]

**Enter Index + Timestamp and "Create data view"**

**Then go back to "Discover" and view the new "view".**
[image]

**You may have to "change data view"**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open kibana url.
2. Click on the Settings tab.
3. Check "Index contains time-based events"
4. Enter the index name/pattern in the textbox for index.

   For example - if index in ES is "abc-2016.12.11", u can enter "abc*" pattern and click outside.
5. "Create" button will be activated. Click it.
6. Click on the "Discover" tab and select the index from the dropdown as in the snapshot shown with index "games*".

[image]

7. We can see the data.

Comment: Than kyou very much.Image url is blocked by our company.Can you share by alternative ?

Comment: below the search criteria in discover tab on the left side, there is a dropdown to select the index name/pattern.

Comment: Where can i find discover tab ?

Comment: Try to access the link where the attached snapshot can be downloaded. If u can find the Settings tab.."Discover" is the left most tab.